# Excel Macro copying poorly formatted data into table

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have been tasked with extracting data out of an Excel sheet that is strangely/poorly formatted. There is far too much data to manually copy out, so I am trying to use a Macro. I am not very skilled with VBA, but I know a little (probably just enough to break something :) ).

I am just working on 1 sheet right now, but there are several sheets, all formatted in the same way. Here is a snippet of what the source data looks like:
I highlighted the cells that I am needing to copy. The rest of the data is not important and won't need to be extracted.

[image]

As you can see, the source data is not formatted as traditional rows and columns, to say the least.

I am copying this data into a table that I have set up in a new sheet. [image]

****Edit:**** I updated my code. I realized that the data was formatted to where there are the same amount of spaces between the rows in the data that I need, 14 to be exact. I now have a Do While Loop that increments the Row Index by 14 each time to move to the next record.

This code works, but am I going about this the correct way??? I will need to repeat this process for about 50 sheets, some of which have 1000 or more records.

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
Dim DestRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

Set SourceSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set DestSheet = Sheets("Data")

Do While i < 100
    DestRow = DestSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    SourceSheet.Cells(2 + i, 1).Copy
    DestSheet.Range("A" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    SourceSheet.Cells(2 + i, 2).Copy
    DestSheet.Range("D" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    SourceSheet.Cells(3 + i, 2).Copy
    DestSheet.Range("E" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    SourceSheet.Cells(4 + i, 2).Copy
    DestSheet.Range("F" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    SourceSheet.Cells(2 + i, 7).Copy
    DestSheet.Range("C" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    SourceSheet.Cells(5 + i, 7).Copy
    DestSheet.Range("G" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    SourceSheet.Cells(14 + i, 2).Copy
    DestSheet.Range("B" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    i = i + 14
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting the *almost* final code I came up with here in case it can help any one in the future. It turned out to not be quite as hard as I thought, once I discovered there was equal spacing in the data. Thanks @Doug Glancy for your advice on using `Exit Do`.

I am sure this is far from a perfect solution. Need to add some error handling/checking. I would appreciate any advice on ways that the code could be improved, or different ways to accomplish this.

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
Dim DestRow As Long
Dim i As Integer


Set DestSheet = Sheets("Data")

'Loop through all worksheets in the workbook
For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

'Reset counter variable for each worksheet
i = 0

    'Check to make sure we are not on the destination sheet
    If Worksheet.Name <> DestSheet.Name Then

        'Loop through all rows in the sheet
        Do While i < Worksheet.Rows.Count

            'Check the contents of the first row in the record to ensure that it contains data
            If Worksheet.Cells(2 + i, 1) <> "" Then

                'Find the next empty row in the destination sheet to copy to
                DestRow = DestSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                'Copy and paste data, using paste special because of the formatting and formulas in the source
                Worksheet.Cells(2 + i, 1).Copy
                DestSheet.Range("A" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                Worksheet.Cells(2 + i, 2).Copy
                DestSheet.Range("D" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                Worksheet.Cells(3 + i, 2).Copy
                DestSheet.Range("E" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                Worksheet.Cells(4 + i, 2).Copy
                DestSheet.Range("F" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                Worksheet.Cells(2 + i, 7).Copy
                DestSheet.Range("C" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                Worksheet.Cells(5 + i, 7).Copy
                DestSheet.Range("G" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                Worksheet.Cells(14 + i, 2).Copy
                DestSheet.Range("B" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                'Add 14 to counter, since the rows are equally spaced by 14
                i = i + 14

            Else

            'If the first row contains no data, then exit the loop
                Exit Do

            End If
        Loop

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I would mark this as the answer. As to error-checking for a one-off that you run yourself, I wouldn't bother. For a beginner you have a good feel for this, so hopefully you'll get to use VBA for something more lasting. That said, the satisfaction from writing something like this that reduces hours of labor to the click of a button is great.

Comment: Thanks I've never actually answered my own question  before so I wasn't sure exactly how that worked. I will mark as answer as soon as it will let me. Problems and solutions like this are exactly what I love about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think what you are doing is good. You've figured out the pattern and how to increment through it. You probably want to add some kind of check for when you've reached the end of a sheet - the simplest would be to test for a blank in the first line after the `Do` and exit that loop with an `Exit Do` which will kick you into an outer loop like `For each ws in wb.Worksheets`.

This isn't a very technical answer I know, but it seems like you're very close and I didn't want to type all this in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Like I said, I don't have much experience with VBA, but this project is definitely helping me learn a little.